# VS Code: No process running with Id error when attaching to ASP.NET Core process in Docker container

Tags: docker, debugging, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

Currently I'm running ASP.NET Core directly on my Linux workstation. But I want to directly develop with Docker, including remote debugging. Following different articles, it seems that vsdbg is required. So I tried the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
RUN apt update && \
    apt install unzip && \
    curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish
WORKDIR /app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish/
ENTRYPOINT dotnet MyApp.dll
```

The docker container is started and I can access my ASP.NET Core app in the browser. VS Code should attach with the following `launch.json` snippet:

```
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/app": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "pipeTransport": {
            "pipeProgram": "docker",
            "pipeArgs": ["exec", "-i", "my-docker-container-name"],
            "debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg",
            "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "quoteArgs": false
        }
    }
```

After running this debug attach entry, It shows a select list with process ids. The first one contains `dotnet MyApp.dll` so this must be my docker process. But after selecting, VS Code shows a popup that currently no process is running with the selected id.

The process id IS correct. I tried running `kill <pid>` and my dotnet process in the docker container exited.

#### So why VS Code breaks with the error that the docker process is not running?

#### System information:

- Ubuntu 19.04
- Docker 19.03.0-rc3
- VS Code 1.35.1

#### Edit

Seems to be something to do with `quoteArgs`. When I set this to false, another error occurs:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/vsdbg/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode\": stat /vsdbg/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode: no such file or directory": unknown

Without the quotes, he try to execute `"/usr/bin/docker" exec -i <my-docker-container-name> /vsdbg/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode`. I executed this manually and it starts vsdbg and keep the terminal open. So `quoteArgs: false` seems correct for Docker. Altough I doesn't understand why this gave the strange *no process running with pid* error in VS Code.

Comment: I fail to reproduce your issue. What is the command to build and run the container?

Comment: First I used docker-compose in attached mode (`docker-compose up --build`). Now I also tried to build a image manually with `docker build -t aspnetcore-test .` and run `docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 --name aspnetcore-test aspnetcore-test:latest`. Doesn't work, also not in detached mode.